# Recover a sandbox after accidental refresh/deletion

Tags: sandbox, support, sandbox-refresh, refresh

I have refreshed my sandbox accidentally. Is there a way to get back the old copy of my sandbox?

I did not use clear case or svn.

Comment: I can't give a specific person I spoke to, as this org happened to have premier support with a customer success rep.  Even if you do not have premier support, you just need to raise it as urgent and get it escalated as fast as you can to fit into the window

Comment: just curious @suneetha, were you able to recover the sandbox?

Answer (score 37):

Salesforce actually can revert this change for up to 72 hours after the refresh/deletion.  I have run into this exact issue, and SF support was able to revert the sandbox back.  You just need to make sure you contact them within 72 hours.  Although our Customer Success Rep told us that they can usually get it for up to a week, they only commit to 72 hours, so I wouldn't push my luck.

I can't find this documented anywhere, but I know this to be true as I had them do it for me about 2 months ago.  I would open a ticket with Support ASAP.

See the below screenshot of an email between our SF admin and our SF customer Success Rep.

[image]

Comment: The more you know...

Answer (score 4):

A refreshed sandbox replaces the existing sandbox data with the refreshed version from production. It is a permanent operation.

Your sandbox data is still there if you have not activated your sandbox yet. Activating a sandbox replaces all previous data with current data.

Only steps you can do is If you have your code on eclipse you can deploy it again to the sandbox. However previous Data cannot be retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

Did you activated it?
Anyway get in touch with support asap. create a ticket and describe your trouble. It might be fixed only on salesforce support side.

Comment: I have activated it as well. In eclipse, I have only triggers,classes,pages,components and static resources.